# Leaflet.js with a vector layer is very slow

Tags: performance, javascript, leaflet

I played around with leaflet.js and found it to be very slow with a simple vector layer containing around 200 circles. The first page load takes several seconds and it's more or less not possible to zoom or scroll the map, the reaction of the page is incredible slow. As I've seen much more complicated leaflet examples, I'm pretty sure I did something wrong. Here the code of my test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
       rel="stylesheet"
       href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"
       />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 1100px; height: 550px"></div>
    <script
       src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>
    <script>

var points = [ 
[ 48.538385 , 11.166186 ],
...
];
      var map = L.map('map').setView([51.0, 10.20], 6);
      mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
      L.tileLayer(
      'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; ' + mapLink,
      maxZoom: 16,
      }).addTo(map);

     for ( var i = 0;  i < points.length; i++) {
    var c = L.circle([points[i][0], points[i][1]], 20);
    c.addTo(map);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code seems fine. You could try one of the global override switches to force drawing with canvas (L_PREFER_CANVAS). The "use-case" that's documented on the reference page seems to address your exact issue:

From: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#global

> **L_PREFER_CANVAS**
>   Forces Leaflet to use the Canvas back-end (if
>   available) for vector layers instead of SVG. This can increase
>   performance considerably in some cases (***e.g. many thousands of circle
>   markers on the map***).

Comment: WOW! That does make things faster!

Comment: Note that this switch is now part of the map instead of a global "switch".